# Python script for finding intersections for a graph function

Tags: python, function, math, graph

I have this python code for finding intersections in the function "f(x)=x**2+x-2" with "g(x)=6-x"

```
import math 


#brute force the functions with numbers until his Y values match, and then, do this for the other point.

def funcs():
    
    for X in range(-100, 100):

        funcA = (X**2)+X-2
        funcB = 6 - X

        if funcA == funcB:
            print("##INTERSECTION FOUND!!")
            print(f"({X},{funcA})")
            print(f"({X},{funcB})")
        else:
            pass



funcs()
```

But my problem is the script only works with THAT SPECIFIC MATH FUNCTION, if I try to change the math function a little bit, the code won't work.

The code just checks when the Y values of the f(x) and the g(x) match together, and do the same for the other point.

Here it is the output:

```
##INTERSECTION FOUND!!
(-4,10)
(-4,10)
##INTERSECTION FOUND!!
(2,4)
(2,4)
```

Comment: Your problem is probably that you only test integers in your ```for``` loop as candidates for the intersection points. If you change your functions a little bit such that the corresponding intersection points are non-integers, you will not find the results.

Comment: Hey @Jan, I tested converting the results to a float value, but it returned the same problem, could you give me some example or inspiration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, this is a root finding problem.

Define `h(x) = f(x) - g(x)`.
The intersection point `x` implies `f(x)=g(x)` or `h(x)=0`.

For root-finding problems, there are many methods, say, bisection method, newton's method.

Here is a numerical example with bisection method.

```
def f(x):
    return x ** 2 + x - 2


def g(x):
    return 6 - x


def h(x):
    return f(x) - g(x)


def bisection(a, b):
    eps = 10 ** -10

    ha = h(a)
    hb = h(b)
    if ha * hb > 0:
        raise ValueError("Bad input")

    for i in range(1000):  # fix iteration number
        ha = h(a)
        midpoint = (a + b) / 2
        hm = h(midpoint)

        if abs(hm) < eps:
            return midpoint

        if hm * ha >= 0:
            a = midpoint
        else:
            b = midpoint

    raise RuntimeError("Out of iterations")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(bisection(0, 100))
    print(bisection(-100, 0))
```

Output:

```
1.999999999998181
-3.999999999996362
```

Why the numbers so close but not exact? because the problem is solved numerically. Other answers that utilize the `sympy` package solves the problem symbolically, which give the exact answer. But they only work with simple problems.

Why `[0, 100]` and `[-100, 0]`? this is because I sketched the graph somehow and know there is a root within the interval. In practice, the bisection method requires the interval `[a,b]` such that `h(a) * h(b) < 0`. Given a big interval `[-100,100]` and, thus, `h(-100) * h(100) > 0`, bisection method does not work this case. The big interval is partitioned such that some of the sub-intervals `[a,b]` satisfy the condition `h(a) * h(b) < 0`, say, `[-100, 0]` and `[0, 100]`

Why `abs(hm) < eps`? This tests whether `hm` is close to `0`. In computers, we consider two floating-point numbers equal if the absolute value of their difference `abs(hm)` is smaller than a threshold `eps`. `eps` is usually `10 ** -10` to `10 ** -15` because there are usually 15 decimal significant digits for float numbers in Python or computer.

Newton's method will give you one of the outputs depending on the initial point.
For further study, search `root finding problem` or `numerical root finding`.

Answer (score 0):

You could employ [sympy](http://docs.sympy.org/), Python's symbolic math library:

```py
from sympy import symbols, Eq, solve

X = symbols('X', real=True)
funcA = (X ** 2) + X - 2
funcB = 6 - X
sol = solve(Eq(funcA, funcB))
print(sol) # --> [-4, 2]
```

To obtain the corresponding values for `funcA` and `funcB`

```
for s in sol:
    print(f'X={s}  funcA({s})={funcA.subs(X, s)}  funcB({s})={funcB.subs(X, s)}  ')

# X=-4  funcA(-4)=10  funcB(-4)=10  
# X=2  funcA(2)=4  funcB(2)=4
```

For some functions, the result could still be symbolically, as that is the most exact form. `.evalf()` obtains a numeric approximation. For example:

```py
funcA = X ** 2 + X - 2
funcB = - 2*X ** 2  + X + 7
sol = solve(Eq(funcA, funcB))
for s in sol:
    print(f'X={s}  funcA(X)={funcA.subs(X, s)}  funcB(X)={funcB.subs(X, s)}')
    print(f'X={s.evalf()}  funcA(X)={funcA.subs(X, s).evalf()}  funcB(X)={funcB.subs(X, s).evalf()}')
```

Output:

```py
X=-sqrt(3)  funcA(X)=1 - sqrt(3)  funcB(X)=1 - sqrt(3)  
X=-1.73205080756888  funcA(X)=-0.732050807568877  funcB(X)=-0.732050807568877  

X=sqrt(3)  funcA(X)=1 + sqrt(3)  funcB(X)=1 + sqrt(3)  
X=1.73205080756888  funcA(X)=2.73205080756888  funcB(X)=2.73205080756888
```

Comment: It worked, but i was mean to get two results. The coordinates of the point A and the point B. The code returned just the coordinates of the point B.

Answer (score 0):

As you want the intersection, hence you are looking for a solution for `f(x) - g(x) = 0`. So, you can use `fsolve` in python to find the root of `f(x) - g(x)`:

```py
from scipy.optimize import fsolve

def func(X):
    funcA = (X ** 2) + X - 2
    funcB = 6 - X
    return (funcA - funcB)

x = fsolve(func,0)
print(x)
```